Best way to use auth0 for managing permissions in a chat application where we might have roles like group admin or regular group member
So I way developing a chat application and kinda stuck while setting roles, permissions, scopes etc. So I was using auth0 for authorization along with OIDC for authentication.
The components of my application are

Android app developed using flutter
Nodejs backend
And Auth0 (Authorization code flow and PKCE)

In the chat app there will be groups where multiple members can be added. There will be two types of members
1. Regular members: Who can send messages to the groups
2. Admins: Who will have all the things a regular member can do plus some extra privileges like
changing group name, adding new member etc.
I want to know what is the best way to implement a solution for handling the roles and permissions.
For example If someone is admin of one group it does not mean he will be admin of other groups .
So if person A is admin of group G1 and I gave him a role of admin he will get the permission to do admin things may be in other groups as well even though he might not be the admin in that group.
So how can I create such group specific roles. As the groups are not ore-decided and may be added dynamically by the users.
I understand this is not a unique problem and there are many services already has such features like WhatsApp. I just want to know what is the auth0 way or in other words OAuth2 way of solving this problem.
I tried creating two permissions

GROUP_MEMBER for regular members
GROUP_ADMIN for admins

But as I said in the problem that the group admin should be group specific so I need to restrict his admin privileges within specific group only. I'm using OAuth2 for the first time and I'm confused how to implement that.

CLAIMS
I would drive behaviour from your APIs. Design an access token with only stable claims. This enables you to identify the user and their high level privileges:

subject
other user IDs if needed
role=member or role=admin

Then, manage group permissions in your APIs. These are your business privileges that change often. Since they are not in access tokens, all chat clients can get up to date values from your APIs.
OAuth is not meant to manage volatile business permissions for you. They are easiest to manage and evolve with the above type of separation.
Claims are used for authorization per user. They help to lock down your access tokens and give your APIs the main values they need for authorization (but not necessarily the finer-grained details).
SCOPES
Scopes set boundaries on backend access but are the same for all users. Often, scopes represent a business area. Eg use a scope of chat to prevent your access tokens from being usable at non-chat-related APIs.

So if I get you correct then,
For example if I've an access token like this
{   sub: 12345,   role: admin }
The role: admin claim does not signify whether or not he is a group admin. Group level things like admin/regular-user  shall be checked in the resource API and not in auth0. In my case I've to run a query to the database to know whether he is actually a group admin or not.

Yes - let Auth0 manage core identity values and your APIs manage group permissions, which Auth0 does not need to know about. Enforce all of the correct rules in your APIs.
